# How to find an element in Salesforce applauncher pop up using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium and Salesforce. I am writing a script to login to salesforce, click on the [Applauncher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDfMN.png) and then click on "Marketing". Below is the script I wrote to do so. But it works out till opening the applauncher [Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlX6n.png). After that, it's unable to find the "Marketing" element from the pop up. I am not sure if it is a pop up or a child page or another window. But I am stuck here & stuggling for last 2 days and its really annoying. Below is the code. Please help.

```
public class Marketing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\fld\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
    
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
 
 driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("**username**@****.com");
 driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("****Password****");

 driver.findElement(By.id("rememberUn")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
 
 Thread.sleep(10000L);
 
 driver.findElement(By.className("slds-icon-waffle")).click();
 Thread.sleep(20000L);
 
 //Code to click the "Marketing" Link goes here.
 /* Below are the failed attempts to click "Marketing" in the pop up.
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p[css='2']")).click();
 
 
 
 
String mainWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
 driver.switchTo().
 System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles().toString());
 for (String childWindowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
      //If window handle is not main window handle then close it 
      if(!childWindowHandle.equals(mainWindowHandle)){
      driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandle);
      // Close child windows
      //driver.close(); 
      break;
      }
    } 
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
         .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='al-menu-dropdown-apps-id-95']/one-app-launcher-menu-item[2]/a")));//"Marketing" item from popup
 myDynamicElement.click();
     
 //driver.findElement(By.className("slds-r2")).click();
 //Thread.sleep(10000L);
 
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("launcher-menu/div/div/one-app-launcher-menu-item[2]/a/div/lightning-formatted-rich-text/span/p")).click();
 //System.out.println("*********************Element: "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='al-menu-dropdown-apps-id-95']/one-app-launcher-menu-item[2]/a")).toString());
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='07p2w0000002LxFAAU']/div")).click(); */

}
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the web site and a valid username and password?

Comment: @Prophet The link to the website is in the code and no one should be sharing credentials unless it's a test site and SalesForce isn't a test site.

Comment: You are right, Jeff. I just wished to login and see the web page there to try help. Without that I will not be able to do a thing.

Comment: It's not a popup or other window... it's still in the original window from the screenshot. My guess is that it's in an IFRAME or similar if you aren't able to locate it. If it's not an IFRAME, test your locator in the browser... use `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPaths, e.g. `$$("p[css='2']"). If more than one element is returned, make sure that the element you are looking for is first... if it's not, then you'll need to find a different locator. You should post the relevant HTML around that Marketing menu so we can check the locator.

Comment: @Prophet Yeah... I agree. Problems behind credentialed sites are the worst... we just have to keep asking questions or just move on to the next question...

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//p[text() ='Marketing']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no iframes there.
The `Marketing` label element XPath locator is

```
//a[@data-label="Marketing"]
```

So you can use this code

```
marketingLabelXpath = "//a[@data-label='Marketing']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(marketingLabelXpath)).click();
```

Or if you prefer CSS Selectors

```
marketingLabelCss = "a[data-label='Marketing']";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(marketingLabelCss)).click();
```

Comment: Getting this exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[data-label='Marketing']"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.77)

Comment: Do you still have a sleep before that?

Comment: It should work in the same way, but if cssSelecotr doesn't work maybe try the Xpath above? Also, if none of the above try this XPath: `//a[@data-label="Marketing"]/..` but they should all work...